# "address already in use" error after forwarding ports between WSL2 and Windows

Tags: wsl-2, portforwarding, netsh

Port-forwarding with `netsh interface portproxy` is somehow blocking the ports that processes on WSL2 need to use.

I ran a PowerShell script from [this blog](https://jwstanly.com/blog/article/Port+Forwarding+WSL+2+to+Your+LAN/) in order to do port-forwarding between WSL2 and Windows 11.

However, when I start some applications that are supposed to bind the ports, it shows "address already in use" errors.

Error from docker-compose service (MongoDB):

```
ERROR: for service_name_1  Cannot start service mongo: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint service_name_1: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use
```

Error from FastAPI:

```
[Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Strange thing is that these errors occur when there are no WSL processes up on those ports.
Running these commands in WSL give me nothing:

```bash
lsof -i :27017
sudo netstat -nlp | grep 27017
```

However, there is one Windows process (svchost) that is using the port:

```
PS > Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 27017

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProces
                                                                                                                        s
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- ------------
0.0.0.0                             27017     0.0.0.0                             0          Listen                     12732

PS > Get-Process -Id 12732

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    401      45     2824      11268       0.05  12732   0 svchost
```

When I kill this process, the "address already in use" errors do not appear anymore, but port-forwarding doesn't work propertly still. They were working just fine until today, and I can't figure out what could have possibly gone wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was running into this same problem from the latest WSL release!

What worked for me is upgrading to a preview version of WSL that fixes this issue.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/1.2.1

After installing the preview msixbundle, worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this. I can confirm that running `wsl --update --pre-release` (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9921)) fixed this issue.